# Firestore onSnapshot() and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

so I am currently working on a project, where I need a realtime datastream of a pool object and a user object. As I am using Firebase as a BAAS, I tried to refactor my code with onSnapshot, as this seemed to minimize requests to the database.

Objective: On Mounting of the component, set a realtime Listener on the pool object, which changes the state which stores the poolData, everyTime there is a change. Based on this up to date pool data, run a calculation every Second, which also updates other states.

Status Quo: When I am rebuilding my project (nextjs) it works for a few instances but then an error occurs when trying to access the pool object *Error occured in getting Pool Time TypeError: Cannot read properties of null*

I was thinking that maybe it throws an error because the standard value for state is set as null, so in the useEffect hook I tried to conventionally fetch a snapshot of the data first, but this also didn't seem to work. Furthermore I am pretty sure I am messing something up regarding the intricacies of useEffect and onSnapshot.
I really appreciate your help and your input!

```
const router = useRouter();
  const slug = router.query.slug;
  const profile = `/profile/${auth.currentUser.uid}`

 const [timerDisplay, setTimerDisplay] = useState(0);
  const [finalTime, setFinalTime] = useState(0);
  const [tokenState, setTokenState] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const [currentlyWinning, setCurrentlyWinning] = useState("Nobody");

  const [poolData, setPoolData] = useState(undefined);

  console.log(poolData);
  useEffect(() => {
    getFirstPoolSnap();
    const unsubPoolListener = onSnapshot(doc(db, "pools", slug), (doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
      setPoolData(doc.data());
    });

    const unsubTokenListener = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid),
      (doc) => {
        setTokenState(doc.data().tokens);
      }
    );

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getPoolTime();
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  function getPoolTime() {
    try {
      let localTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const gbTimeLeft =
        poolData.expTimestamp.toMillis() / 1000 - localTime;
      const finalTimeLeft =
        poolData.finalTime.toMillis() / 1000 - localTime;
      setOpen(poolData.open);
      if (gbTimeLeft < 0 || finalTimeLeft < 0) {
        setTimerDisplay(0);
      } else {
        setTimerDisplay(Math.floor(gbTimeLeft));
      }
      if (finalTimeLeft < 0 || gbTimeLeft < 0) {
        setFinalTime(0);
      } else {
        setFinalTime(Math.floor(finalTimeLeft));
      }
      setCurrentlyWinning(poolData.lastSetterName);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error occured in getting Pool Time", error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `slug` isn't defined anywhere in your code snippet. You can call doc.exists to make sure your document was successfully fetched before trying to read the properties. What does `console.log(doc.data());` print right before your error is thrown?

Comment: Try initializing poolData in the following way:
 ```const [poolData, setPoolData] = useState([]);```

Comment: @Chris sorry I missed a part of the code snipped, post is edited and slug defined